# Which general linear model should I use for my data

Tags: statistics

I have some data that I need to find a GLM for. However, I'm stuck on which family and link to choose.

The data is the number of students attending a class and the average score of the homework for 11 weeks. The scores are a number out of 50, I wondered if divided all the scores I'd then use binomial, but I'm not sure if that's right at all, and I've got no idea for the link, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think I may have been wrong about the response variable, as I think I need to show what factors affect attendance, therefore attendance is the response. Upon realising this it's my thinking that a poisson distribution would be suitable since it is count data.

Comment: In order to give an answer, it would help to know your purpose in analyzing these scores. To compare with data from other classes? To see if there is improvement over the 11 weeks? To use some other data to predict future perfomance in the class?

Comment: So the idea is to monitor and improve attendance, so I think I need to show how scores improve as attendance does.

Comment: Then you should think in terms of regression models. Regress scores on predictor variable attendance. Before or after (and before taking results seriously) check for linearity, normality, good behavior or residuals, and whether prediction intervals are short enough to be useful. If trying to 'predict' future scores remember "Prediction is difficult, especially about the future."

Comment: Thank you for the help, however please see my edit as I think I got it a bit confused. Thanks.